# How To use Database as a variable with blade template in laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-blade

i'm new in laravel, i have some problem to make database as variable to be shown on blade template,
example i want to get any data from database :

```
{{$get = DB::table('perangkat')->get()}}
```

then:

```
@foreach ($get as $got)
   {{$got->jabatan}}
@endforeach
```

if the result of the `$got->jabatan` is `kepala`, But i want the result is Change To `"Kepala Desa"`, How can i do ??
Please Help Mee ...

Comment: You can use normal php tags for that. `<?php $get = DB::table('perangkat')->get(); ?>`. But why would you want to do this? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write database related stuff in model or controller in a method and pass that value to view. It will be very neat and clear

```
public function getData(){

    $get = DB::table('perangkat')->get();

    return view('myblade', ['data' => $get]);
}
```

In your view

```
@foreach ($data as $got)
   {{$got->jabatan}} Desa
@endforeach
```

Also can you update where you get **Desa** .so i can update answer according to that.

**Updated**
you keep different roles in array and do some think like this

```
 <?php
    $role=['a'=>'operator','b'=>'admin'] ; ?>

      @foreach ($data as $got)
  <?php  $result = isset($role[$got->jabatan]) ? $role[$got->jabatan] : null; ?>
           {{$result}} 
        @endforeach
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,  but i want to change the `kepala` as a variable,

Comment: example result of '$got->jabatan' is `a` then the `a` is change to `Administrator`, and if the result is `b` then the `b` is change to `Operator`..

Answer (score 0):

company.php

```
function showdata{
$sql= "this syntax sql";
}

//show data
$company = new company();
@foreach ($company->showdata() as $got)
  {{$got->jabatan}}
    @endforeach
```